# PHP How to get event attendings email using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm very new in FB Graph and I want to get the attendings list of an event with, if possible, the email of each one.
Now, after some work:

In the login script:

I set the "email" permission

```
$permissions = ['email']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://xxxx', $permissions);
```

In the callback:

I get attending list (but Name and Id only)

For each attending I call

```
$request = $fb->request('GET', '/'. $attending['id'].'?fields=id,name,email');
$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$email = $graphObject->getProperty('email');  // This is not getting any thing
```

But cannot get the email addresses.

Doing some tests I replaced the $attending['id'] withe 'me'_

```
$request = $fb->request('GET', '/me?fields=id,name,email');
```

and I got my email address.

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks for your answer.

Marcello

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the email of a user who authorized your App with the `email` permission. There is no way to get the attendees including their emails - for obvious reasons, you would not be allowed to store or use their emails in any way without their explicit permission to do so.

Comment: Thanks, so I suppose is the same thing with addresses or any other personal attendees information.

Comment: of course, you need specific permissions for additional data. you can´t just grab those things even if they are public on facebook.com, you need permission from each user.